# PowerPivot Sort by Column with VBA/C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba, powerpivot

is it in any way possible to access the "Sort by Column" functionality in PowerPivot in Excel via VBA or even C#?

The functionality I mean is in Tab->PowerPivot->Manage and then "Sort By Column" for a specific Table:

[image]

Comment: I've done just a bit of programming of PowerPivot with VBA. I had to build a formula string in VBA that I copied from PowerPivot, e.g.: `ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=TableName, Formula:= _
"let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook()` with the specific actions after that. I did a quick web search and came up this this, for example: https://excelunplugged.com/2018/01/23/modifying-power-query-m-code-with-vba/

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your answer. You are referring to Power Query and not Power Pivot right?

Comment: Woops, probably, I can't keep them straight. Good luck!

Comment: I looked through the PowerPivot object model and can't find anything that would help.